# Анимация сектора круга

Tags: canvas, html, javascript, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто реализовывал такую штуку. Eсть картинка (круглая) r=210.
При движении мышкой по часовой стрелке картинка закрывается сектором синего цвета на расстояние дуги пройденной мышью. т.е если двигаем мышку (образно говоря) до 6 часов (проходим пол круга) - то слева получаем половину картинки, справа- синий полукруг, двигаем на 9 часов - видим четверть картинки и 3/4 синего непрозрачного синего круга. Изменение должно происходить плавно, вслед за движением мыши. Можно двигаться по часовой стрелке и против (соответственно эффект обратный - видим больше картинки).

Большое спасибо за помощь! :)

Comment: думаю, вам нужно на фриланс.

Comment: kineticjs или еще какая-нить либа вам подойдет

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого? Допилить только чтобы картинка вместо синего цвета была.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdgtA/

( LibCanvas )

Comment: вы читер :D

Comment: Почему? ^^

Comment: Да, то что нужно! :)Спасибо!

Comment: Думаю, корректно будет ответ пометить как "решение")